# MYSQL - Retrieve all child IDs in one column, given a parent ID

Tags: mysql

I am trying to achieve the following say I have a table:

```
products_id    products_master
--------------------------------
1                    0
2                    0
3                    0
4                    2
5                    2
6                    2
7                    3
8                    3
```

I then want to be able to return a column when selecting the parent row with all its children so when I select other columns from products_id = 2

I want the following result:

```
products_id     products_master    simples_skus
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                     0              4,5,6
```

I hope this makes sense! If you need further clarification please do ask! This is on MYSQL :)

EDIT: The first answer I received has made me realise something extra.

I should have mentioned that I want this to work without me specifying which ID I am after. So for example I am selecting all products which have a master 0 (meaning they themselves are a master product) and I am trying to get child IDs for the master products IF THEY EXIST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your clarification, your SQL query is:

```
SELECT t1.products_id, t1.products_master, group_concat(t2.products_id) AS simple_skus
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.products_id = t2.products_master
WHERE t1.products_id = 2
GROUP BY t1.products_master
```

Explanation: you need to use your table twice:
 1. once (`t2`) for `group_concat()`
 2. once (`t1`) for expressing your selection (`t1.products_id = 2`)

Comment: Hi there, the other columns can be ignored, I'll throw them in myself as they are pretty tricky (it is a very long statement so I assumed it would be irrelevant) regarding the simples_skus I need them to be 4,5,6 for sure. I am trying to get all the children that have the same parent as the row I am selecting. All columns mentioned (that are relevant) are in the same table. I'm going to try out your query now :)

Comment: Ok buddy will do that now, I edited the question further as I realised another issue. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

With a table like the following:

```
Create table bla( 
  products_id    int,
  products_master int,
  x int,
  y int
  );
```

and sample values:

```
insert into bla  VALUES (1,0,8,9);
insert into bla VALUES  (2,0,9,10);
insert into bla  VALUES (3,0,10,11);
insert into bla VALUES  (4,2,11,12);
insert into bla VALUES  (5,2,12,13);
insert into bla VALUES  (6,2,13,14);
insert into bla VALUES  (7,3,14,15);
insert into bla VALUES  (8,3,16,16);
```

the sql that you want is:

```
 SELECT masterbla.products_id,masterbla.products_master,masterbla.x,masterbla.y, group_concat(minorbla.products_id)
 FROM bla AS masterbla INNER JOIN bla AS minorbla ON masterbla.products_id=minorbla.products_master
 WHERE masterbla.products_master=0
 GROUP BY masterbla.products_id
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64ffa/12)

EDIT: If you want to also fetch entry with product id '1' (a master entry without minor entries) use this one instead:

```
SELECT masterbla.products_id,masterbla.products_master,masterbla.x,masterbla.y, group_concat(minorbla.products_id)
FROM bla AS masterbla LEFT JOIN bla AS minorbla ON masterbla.products_id=minorbla.products_master
WHERE masterbla.products_master=0
GROUP BY masterbla.products_id
```

Comment: I really liked your answer as well. Very simple and well laid out :)